# Paperclip attachment file size

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, attachment, filesize

How do I fetch the file size of each style of a paperclip attachment?

`@user.attachment_file_size` doesn't seem to work

```
@user.attachment(:style).size
```

gives a number not related to the actual file size

Comment: Latest version of paperclip doesn't give me the file_size either. Not sure what's up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find either how to get the file size **for a given style**, other than the original one.

As seen [in the paperclip source code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L274), `@user.attachment.size` returns the size of the file as originally assigned. There is no way to get it for a specific style...

A solution would be:

```
open(@user.attachment(:style)).size
```

But not efficient at all.

To do it well, you should probably add some "custom size" fields in your attachment table that you would fill once the attachment is saved for each style...

Comment: Hi Pierrea, probably no longer an issue for you. But I have found a solution answered below, by catching the temp file for each style before uploading to S3.

Answer (score 4):

User find by ID(for example) 
User has :photo

```
@user.last.photo_file_size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a string like "WIDTHxHEIGHT" inside styles hash, for the giving object's style, using [Paperclip::Style#geometry](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip%2FStyle%3Ageometry):

```
string = @user.attachment.styles[:size].geometry
```

Than you can split the string to have either height or width:

```
width = string.split("x")[0]

height = string.split("x")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**It seems it is possible actually**

Just have to cath the temporary files for each style and applying size method.

let's say you have two styles `large` and `small` for your attachment called `image` and you have created two extra fields in your model `large_size` and `small_size` to save those values.

Just add the below bit of code to your model:

```
before_create :assign_sizes

private
def assign_sizes
    self.large_size = image.queued_for_write[:large].size.to_i
    self.small_size = image.queued_for_write[:small].size.to_i
end
```

The fields `large_size` and `small_size` will be popuated with each style file size. And this will be done before the files are sent to S3 for example. So there is no extra querying the files headers from S3.