# Papierclip and size of style files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to access data about style files generated by `Paperclip`.

Here are my `has_atteched_file` data:

```
has_attached_file :file, {
:url => '/video/sources/:id/:style.:extension',
:path => ':rails_root/videos/:id/:style.:extension',
:styles => {
  :medium => {
    :processors => [:ffmpeg],
    :acodec => 'libmp3lame', :abitrate => '256k',
    :vcodec => 'libx264'   , :vbitrate => '2M',
    :ffmpeg_options => ['-preset', 'fast']
    :format => 'mp4'
  }
}
```

}

Then I've a `medium` style. I would like to have the size of this generated file. I can do that directly by opening it with Ruby method but I was wondering if `Paperclip` has any method to do that and I didn't find it on the documentation.

Currently, I can do:

```
Video.last.file.size
# => Gives me the size of the original file in octets
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
Video.last.file(:medium).size
# This method does not exist. 
# Video.last.file(:medium) gives an url
```

Here is another post about this question with `Ruby` method option: [paperclip-attachment-file-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803185/paperclip-attachment-file-size) and below my code:

```
File.open(Video.last.source.file.path(:medium), 'r') do |f|
 f.size
end
# => Gives me the size of the medium file in octets
```