# Recovering file size of a specific paperclip image style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I need to know the file size of a paperclip attachment image style (not only the `:original` style which has a dedicated field already) and I am a bit struggling at the moment.

- I have found no solution to do that inside the model
- I have installed `paperclip-meta` gem but this gem is actually returning styles dimensions, not file size.
- I might be able to retrieve the file size after the files have been uploaded to S3. I have read something about sending an Http header request or such and parsing return. I am not very at ease with this and it seems a bit complicate as the files have been generated locally and should be accessible by the server at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need. As you mention Paperclip attachments have a database field for the `:original` style file size, but the `size` method just returns that value.

I wanted a quick solution that would allow determining of attachment size in either filesystem or S3 (I use both) and without having to actually perform HTTP header checks. Upon looking at the Paperclip::Storage structure, I realized I could override the `size` method for each storage method by putting the following in my `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`:

```
module Paperclip
  module Storage
    module Filesystem
      def size(style_name = default_style)
        if original_filename
          File.size(path(style_name))
        else
          false
        end
      end
    end

    module S3
      def size(style = default_style)
        if original_filename
          s3_object(style).content_length
        else
          false
        end
      rescue Aws::Errors::ServiceError => e
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `paperclip-meta` gem does appear to have a `size` method, in addition to image dimensions, aspect ratio, etc. I’m not sure if it’s a more recent addition than when you tried it. It has the advantage of caching the values in the DB.

Comment: Thanks Morgant, your solution probably work for S3 but I think it it needs loading the S3 object before getting its `content_length`. I have found a solution by catching the temporary file for each style before it is being sent to S3. It is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803185/paperclip-attachment-file-size

Comment: @Maxence I haven’t investigated the performance, but found it to be adequate for my needs. It must be fetching the S3 object, but probably only a list, not a full fetch of the data. I needed to determine the file size once it was already on S3 (performing various data migrations), but had I needed it prior to upload or to cache it, I’d prefer your solution.